# Complete distance matrix in MapReduce

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, mapreduce, distance-matrix

I am relatively new to MapReduce and the following problem crossed my mind: how can you calculate in MapReduce a complete (i.e. not sparse) distance matrix?

I have a 2D dataset with N instances and I have to evaluate all the possible distances between such points and store them in a matrix.

What I did so far is

- let the Map retrieve its chunk, eval distances between such points: the resulting matrix will be an NxN matrix with some distances and some zeros.
- the Reduce will concatenate (sum) such matrices and then fills the voids (i.e. intra-chunk distances, the still-zero elements)

I reckon that's not very efficient (especially from the memory point of view).

Anyone can enlighten me?

**Update**: I did a bit of optimization in the code above. Now

- the Map receives its chunk and evaluate the distances between such points without preallocating an NxN matrix, but preallocating an Nx3 matrix (1st col in Point A, 2nd col is Point B, 3rd col is dist(A,B))
- the Reducer preallocates an NxN matrix entirely filled with zeros. Now fills the distances (inter-chunk) calculated by the Map and then fills the voids (i.e. intra-chunk distances, the still-zero elements)

A better solution, no doubt, because the Mappers don't need to build the entire NxN matrix but, still, I reckon it can be done better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I did: the Map tasks simply evaluate the distances between a given instance `j` and all the other instances.  The Reducer concatenates such distances in a vector which is written on disk. Such record is indeed the `j`th row of the matrix. This goes on for all the instances and then all the records written on disk are concatenated together.